# How to parse div tag from alexa.com and show results in table in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have successfully created a webapp using `HTMLParser` and `urllib2` that gets the first 20 websites from **www.alexa.com/topsites/global** and put the results in a HTML table. My problem is that I can't follow the same rules and apply the same algorithm for `<div class="count">` and `<div class="description">`.

Can anybody help me with some sort of a snippet for this **without** using BS4 ?

My code so far:

**urlparse.py**

```
import HTMLParser, urllib

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    site_list = []

    def reset(self):
        HTMLParser.HTMLParser.reset(self)
        self.in_a = False
        self.next_link_text_pair = None
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag=='a':
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name=='href':
                    self.next_link_text_pair = [value, '']
                    self.in_a = True
                    break
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.in_a: self.next_link_text_pair[1] += data
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag=='a':
            if self.next_link_text_pair is not None:
                if self.next_link_text_pair[0].startswith('/siteinfo/'):
                    self.site_list.append(self.next_link_text_pair[1])
            self.next_link_text_pair = None
            self.in_a = False

if __name__=='__main__':
    p = MyHTMLParser()
    p.feed(urllib.urlopen('http://www.alexa.com/topsites/global').read())
    print p.site_list[:20]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.top_urls', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def top_urls(request):
    p = MyHTMLParser()
    p.feed(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.alexa.com/topsites/global').read())
    urls = p.site_list[:20]
    print urls
    return render(request, 'top_urls.html', {'urls': urls})
```

**top_urls.html**

```
...
<tbody>
    {% for url in urls %}
        <tr>
            <td>Something</td><!--here should be {{rank}}-->
            <td>{{ url }}</td>
            <td>something</td><!--here should be {{description}}-->
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to create a some kind of a state machine.  In the `starttag` event we decide which data field of the site info should be populated later in the `data` event.  Decision is made on the `<div>`/`<span>` `class` attribute and the `ATTR_FIELDS` map.

For example if the `<div class="count">` tag is started then we will populate the `rank` field of the current `self.site` dictionary.

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):

    ATTR_FIELDS = {'count': 'rank',
                   'description': 'description', 'remainder': 'description'}

    def reset_site(self):
        self.site = {'rank': '', 'url': '', 'description': ''}
        self.in_site_listing = self.data_field = False

    def reset(self):
        HTMLParser.HTMLParser.reset(self)
        self.reset_site()
        self.site_list = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        class_attr = dict(attrs).get('class')
        if tag == 'li' and class_attr == 'site-listing':
            self.in_site_listing = True
        elif self.in_site_listing:
            if tag == 'a':
                if class_attr != 'moreDesc':
                    self.site['url'] = dict(attrs)['href'].replace(
                                                             '/siteinfo/', '')
            elif tag in ['div', 'span']:
                self.data_field = self.ATTR_FIELDS.get(class_attr)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.data_field:
            self.site[self.data_field] += data

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'li' and self.in_site_listing:
            self.site_list.append(self.site)
            self.reset_site()
        self.data_field = None
```

And then change the view and template:

**view.py**

```
def top_urls(request):
    p = MyHTMLParser()
    p.feed(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.alexa.com/topsites/global').read())
    sites = p.site_list[:20]
    return render(request, 'top_urls.html', {'sites': sites})
```

**top_urls.html**

```
...
<tbody>
    {% for site in sites %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ site.rank }}</td>
            <td>{{ site.url }}</td>
            <td>{{ site.description }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
...
```

**EXPLANATION UPDATE**:

Variables used:

- `self.site` - current site info
- `self.in_site_listing' - flag is set to True if we are in the`` tag
- `self.data_field` - key in the site info to add the data
- `ATTR_FIELDS` - a map of the `<div>`/`<span>` classes to the site info keys

The key method is the `handle_starttag()`:

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    # get the tag `class` attribute if any
    class_attr = dict(attrs).get('class')
    # if the tag is `<li class="site-listing">` then set the flag that we
    # should populate the site info
    if tag == 'li' and class_attr == 'site-listing':
        self.in_site_listing = True
    # we a in the site population mode
    elif self.in_site_listing:
        if tag == 'a':
            # `<li class="site-info">` contains two `<a>` tags. We should
            # use the tag withoud `class="moreDesc"` attribute to set the url
            if class_attr != 'moreDesc':
                self.site['url'] = dict(attrs)['href'].replace(
                                                         '/siteinfo/', '')
        elif tag in ['div', 'span']:
            # we are in the `<div>` or `<span>` tag. Get the `class` attribute
            # of the tag and decide which field of the site info we will
            # populate in the `handle_data()` method
            self.data_field = self.ATTR_FIELDS.get(class_attr)
```

So the `handle_data()` is pretty simple:

```
def handle_data(self, data):
    # if we know which field of site info should be populated
    if self.data_field:
        # append the data to this field. Site description is spread in several
        # tags this is why we append data instead of simple assigning.
        self.site[self.data_field] += data
```

Comment: I am getting `no data available in table` again. And I've done all the necessary changes. I am now uodating the answer. Maybe I've omitted something :)

Comment: Make sure that you changed all `urls` by `sites`.  And print `sites` in your view.  Is this list empty or have some data?

Comment: can you please put some comments on the posted code from `MyHTMLParser() class` ? Or just explain the `defs`. Thanks.

Comment: I added some explanation to the answer.